# Sub not wokring

Tags: bash, awk

EX: /a/b/c/getThis

/d/c/d/getThis2

```
awk '{printf " %s",sub(/.*\//,"",$1)}'
```

I have this bash script that calls this awk statement to get the basename of numerous inputs of lines that have paths. I keep on getting 1 as the result of this statement. Not sure how to fix

Comment: `sub` doesn't return replaced string. It just returns whether substitution worked or not. Replaced string is `$1` itself.

Comment: Why not just use `basename`?

Answer (score 2):

Just set `/` as field separator to extract the basename from each line:

```
awk -F'/' '{ print $NF }' file
```

The output (for your current input):

```
getThis
getThis2
```